# Is it secure to use 'app_secret' in URLs when calling Disqus API?

Tags: security, disqus

When you use Disqus API on the server side, you **have to** put 'app_secret' in URLs on every API request. Here is what Disqus doc says:

*If you are using the server-side API, you will need to send api_secret with your secret API key value.*

(https://disqus.com/api/docs/requests/)

When I call URL like this:

`https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/list.json?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}`

I get this error:

`{"code":5,"response":"Invalid API key"}`

When change URL to this:

`https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/list.json?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&api_secret={API_SECRET}`

It works ok.

I think it is very, very dangerous to use secret key in common GET requests. I don't know any other API that would be required to use secret key in GET requests.

What do you think about it?

Comment: FYI, you can't just pass the `access_token`, you can always use `api_key` along with your public key instead of `api_secret` and your secret key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a *server-side* request, so from your server to Disqus.com. The client will never see the URL.

As you are using HTTPS, all that is visible in plaintext is that you made a request to a server at a specific IP address. However, an attacker monitoring your DNS requests or using a reverse DNS lookup can easily determine that the IP address belongs to the server at disqus.com.

So in short: It's safe. An attacker can see that you talk to disqus.com, but everything else is encrypted.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629222/are-querystring-parameters-secure-in-https-http-ssl) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893959/if-you-use-https-will-your-url-params-will-be-safe-from-sniffing) for more.

Comment: Ok, thansk for your answer. Unfortunately disqus also allow to use http, not only https. And this is security issue, http should be prohibited. We also build a little bit special app, where user can see HTTP request in plain text, so we will remove query params for this API.

Comment: @user26204 `Note: We recommend using SSL for all requests to the API, but it is not required for anonymous requests.` Which should mean that it's required for all non-anonymous requests. Have you actually tried using HTTP? And why would the user need see your **server-side** requests? I can think of no scenario where that would be necessary.

Comment: I can do HTTP requests with app_secret in URL. I think, API should not allowed this and the HTTP requests should be rejected. We build very special app for advanced users (developers etc), I cannot talk about it more right now.